# load .txt file with JQUERY AJAX call to a textarea won't work if modified

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i'm trying to load .txt file in a `<textarea>`.

The .txt url is chosen by user with a `<select>`.

The problem is when the text in the textarea change.

My function work only if textarea is clean.

Can u help me?

thanks in advance ;)

mike

HTML

```
<label for="text-template">Text selector:</label>
<select name="text-template" class="select" id="text-template">
    <option value="test1.txt" selected>test.txt</option>
    <option value="test2.txt" selected>test2.txt</option>
    <option value="test3.txt" selected>test3.txt</option>
                </select>

                <div id="loadtext" class="loadtext" onclick="loadFileAsText()"><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i>Load Text</div>

<textarea name="corpo" type="text" class="textarea" id="corpo" wrap="hard" placeholder="Insert text" required></textarea>
```

JQUERY

```
function loadFileAsText()
{
    alert ($("#text-template").val()),   
    $.ajax({
           url : $("#text-template").val(),
           cache : false,
           async: false,
           ifModified : false,
           dataType: "text",
           success : function (data) {
               $("#corpo").html(data);
           }
       });
}
```

:)

Comment: Before putting the data try to empty $("#corpo") with jquery empty command or clear

Comment: hi marco! thanks in advance. if i try to empty with $("#corpo").val(''); jquery will not load anything

Comment: Hi, before this line $("#corpo").html(data); use $("#corpo").val(''); and then $("#corpo").val(data); put an alert between line or use Console to debug it

Comment: Why are you setting async to false? That is the only thing that looks odd to me.

Answer (score 1):

Textareas do not contain HTML. To call `.html()` on a textarea element is invalid and should fail (but then again jQuery never paid much attention to things it "should" do...)

Use `.val()` instead, to set the textarea's value.

Comment: @adeneo It's not HTML, though. After all, `<textarea><b>Bold?</b></textarea>` does not produce bold text in a textarea, now does it?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML content of a textarea is its *default* value. Changing it programatically will only reflect in the UI if the value being displayed is the default value.

Use `val()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
$("#text-template").val("");
```

before the ajax call to clear the textarea and use val() instead of html() for setting the value.

I did notice that if I typed something, the text woudln't change, and clearing the textarea before trying to change it, fixed it. This happens only when using .html(). If you use .val(), you don't even have to clear the textarea.